# Managed Property Boost on Enterprise Search

Tags: search, managed-property, enterprise-search

In the link below, you can find a good example of how to add a relevance boost for documents that have a specific value on some managed property.

Let's say you have a List, with a content type "Products", and you want products with the managed property ProductStatus == Active to show up higher in the search results.

In FAST you can get this behavior by using the ManagedPropertyBoostCollection as illustrated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.extended.administration.schema.managedpropertyboostcollection.aspx).

What I'm looking for, is a way to achieve this with SharePoint Enterprise Search. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible - you would have to implement a custom ranking layer between search and the search result webpart for the sorting.

I would not recommend this for an enterprise - for a custom, specialized searchsite with limited queries it would be an option.

Hope it helps!

Max